# Append multi-values return to func argument

Tags: go

Is it possible to compact this operation?

```go
a, b := obtain2Values()
c = ":)"

process3Values(a, b, c)
```

**into something like this**? (I know this doesn't precisely work, but I'm looking for an alternative, if it exists)

```go
process3Values(obtain2Values(), ":)")
```

Comment: No. In Go there are generally no shortcuts whatsoever (by design).

Answer (score 1):

In short, I'm afraid it isn't. In general, Go is not very good at "compacting" expressions because of its way of returning multiple return values (think errors), which cannot be passed on as a group. This makes it hard to implement chained functional expressions as per Linq in C#, or something like Lodash in JavaScript. You're always forced to handle different return values separately. It makes Go rather laborious to write, but also very explicit, which is the intention - to avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func obtain2Values() (int, int) {
        return 1, 2
}

func process3Values(a, b int, c string){
    fmt.Printf("%v %v %v\n", a, b, c)
}

func main() {
    a, b := obtain2Values()
    process3Values(a, b,":)")
    // process3Values(obtain2Values(), ":)")
}
```

process3Values(obtain2Values(), ":)") does not work:

```
./prog.go:16:16: not enough arguments in call to process3Values
./prog.go:16:30: multiple-value obtain2Values() in single-value context
```